Как реализовать peer-to-peer chat?
Пытался найти примеры кода на различных языках программирования для реализации бессерверного p2p-чата, чтобы понять принцип его создания, но не смог найти подходящих материалов. С чего мне вообще стоит начать, чтобы разработать такое приложение? На каких ресурсах можно подробнее почитать про p2p?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Может про сокеты почитать?

Уже почитал. Проблема в том, что не знаю, как эти знания применить для решения моей задачи. Был бы рад конкретным примерам с интернета.
